# How do I set an alias for a specific command in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

There is a command that I type a lot: `java -jar foo --param1 --param2, --param-n`. How can I create a command alias to run this command like so:

```
launch_foo --param3
```

where `launch_foo` is translated to the full command?

Comment: You'd have to make a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a function. Fortunately, creating an "alias-style" function with standard arguments isn't difficult:

```
Function launch_foo { java -jar foo --param1 --param2 --param-n $args }
```

You can now invoke the function either as `launch_foo` or as `launch_foo --param3`. Note that if you don't pass in any additional arguments, `$args` will be `$null` and will have no effect<sup>[1]</sup> on the default arguments specified in the function.

Now, there is the concept of aliases in Powershell but aliases are alternate names for cmdlets or commands, you can't add arguments to the alias definition. You would use an alias as an alternate executable or cmdlet name. Some examples of aliases:

```
Set-Alias v vim
Set-Alias list Get-ChildItem
Set-Alias 2json ConvertTo-Json
```

`v` would run `vim`, `list` would run `Get-ChildItem`, and `2json` would run `ConvertTo-Json`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Note that this is only true for external commands. If you attempt to alias a cmdlet or function with parameters in this way, a `$null` argument will be evaluated as a `$null` value, which `$args` would be `$null` if not provided. Depending on the cmdlet this could throw an error, have no effect, or have an undesired effect. Depending on the cmdlet, you may also need to splat `@args` to appropriately pass on the arguments.

Comment: Why is it that you cannot set an alias with arguments that read from the input?
I use 'gc -readcount -10 -wait path' ALLOT. SURE would be nice to set and alias with ALL those parameters already ready...

Comment: It's probably a design decision for the language. An alias is just that; an alternative name to use. A wrapper function is not too difficult to write, but I do agree it would be nice if we could easily set aliases with pre-determined arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could also, for example create a `launch_foo.bat` file inside any bin folder that is in the environment variabel `PATH` location.

Then inside the `launch_foo.bat` file you place the command for example: `java -jar foo %*`.

The `%*` is for all argument that comes after the initial command. You could also user `%1` if you only want to use the first argument.

Now you can call the `launch_foo --param3` command from Powershell. For me this solution works like a charm on Windows.