# Error setting alias in PowerShell to Java platform

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 and having trouble setting an alias to a Java platform using PowerShell.

This works in Git Bash:
`alias mytest='java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -cp D:/mypath/myfile.jar myfile.myapp'`

And when I type `mytest` into the Git Bash prompt, it returns:

```
myfile [v11.3.0]

Usage:
  java ...
```

And I can run it without issue in the Git Bash prompt using the alias.

I am trying to learn how to do this in PowerShell also, and here are my attempts and errors:

`Set-Alias -Name "mytest" -Value "java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -cp D:\mypath\myfile.jar myfile.myapp" -Description "An alias to for mytest"`

And when I enter `mytest` in the PowerShell prompt, it returns this error:

```
mytest : The term 'D:\mypath\myfile.jar myfile.myapp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mytest
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\mypath\myfile.jar myfile.myapp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also tried the following, based on [How do I set an alias for a specific command in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379588/how-do-i-set-an-alias-for-a-specific-command-in-powershell), and it returns the same error:
`Function mytest { java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -cp "D:\mypath\myfile.jar myfile.myapp" $args }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aliases in PowerShell are simply alternative *names* for other *commands*, which precludes defining aliases *with (hard-coded) arguments***, the way that POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` allow.

So a ***function* is indeed necessary** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292585/45375) for more information).

The equivalent of the following `bash` alias:

```sh
# bash
alias mytest='java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -cp D:/mypath/myfile.jar myfile.myapp'
```

is this PowerShell function:

```sh
# PowerShell
function mytest { java -Xms1g -Xmx4g -cp D:/mypath/myfile.jar myfile.myapp $args }
```

Note how the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) is needed to pass arguments passed to the function through.